# How to assign ASP variable between jquery function on ASP page?

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

Is there any way to assign ASP variable between jquery function is executing?

```
<%
txtDescription = Replace(strBody,vbCrLf,"<br/>")
%>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    var bodyDefault = '<%=strBodyDefault%>';
    var txtDescription = '<%=txtDescription%>';
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
      $("#obj_edit_editBox").focus(function()
      {
          if (txtDescription == bodyDefault)
          {
        //Do something here
          }
      });                          
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your code should work fine. Are you having a problem with it?

Comment: Hi Rory, in the place `Do something here` .. How can I assign asp variable to empty i.e., `txtDescription = ""`.. I'm stuck up at this point..

Comment: If your ASP variable `txtDescription` is empty or null, then nothing would be ouput in the `response.write` and `var txtDescription = ''` would be written to the page.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in `Do something`?

Comment: Actually, my intention is: `onfocus` then i should set ASP variable 'txtDescription' to empty. if `onblur` then i should assign ASP variable 'strBodyDefault' value to 'txtDescription' ASP variable.

Comment: Siva: In your case I think that you need to create an `input` field named `Description` and set the values in it. Then you need to submit (using a `FORM POST`) the values to the server.
I think that you are no understanding how web development works.

Answer (score 1):

The ASP variables are vanishes as soon as the server ends generating the page and send it to the client. There (in the client) you can play with javascript and then post back to the server (via POST or GET) to process the info.